# MongCollection is not available in mongoC# Driver 2.2.2?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

[image]

From above Image u can observe that I added MongoDB.Driver assembly. But Mongocollection class is not coming.

I checked in references there also No class named Mongocollection under MongoDB.Driver.

I installed using NUget packaage.

If it is removed What is the alternate?

Comment: [`MongoCollection` is in `MongoDB.Driver.Legacy.dll`](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/2.0/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_MongoCollection.htm)

Comment: Yes Now only go through there site They rewrtited Api totally in 2 version